# Client Certificate received null in gRPC implemented in C# Console App

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ssl, grpc

I am implementing a simple gRPC project in C# as listed in [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-3.1). It is very simple and have 2 projects:

1. gRPC service - containing the gRPC service
2. C# console app - that calls the gRPC service

The gRPC service method called code is given below:

```
public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
    var clientCertificate = httpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;

    return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
    {
        Message = "Hello " + request.Name
    });
}
```

Notice I am trying to read the client certificate as:

> **var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();**
>
> **var clientCertificate = httpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;**

***The problem is that I receive null for client certificate. I checked it by putting breakpoint in Visual Studio. Why it is so ?***

The C# console apps which calls this gRPC service is:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // The port number(5001) must match the port of the gRPC server.
    var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(basePath, "client.pfx"), "1234");
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

    var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001/", new GrpcChannelOptions
    {
        HttpClient = httpClient
    });
    var grpc = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
    var response = await grpc.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "Bob" });
    Console.WriteLine(response.Message);
}
```

Here I am adding the certificate in code lines:

> **var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(basePath, "client.pfx"), "1234");**
>
> **var handler = new HttpClientHandler();**
>
> **handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);**

**Why is the certificate received null?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after doing a lot of research and hope it helps others too. In the gRPC service project, go to `CreateHostBuilder()` function of the `Program.cs` and ***configure Kestrel to require client certificate***. The below code lines are the ones doing this work:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                //configure to require client certificate
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
                {
                    o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
                        o.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);
                });
            });
```